# How to use the word "like"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, negation

A friend and I were having a conversation about certain characters in a game we both play. He was going on about how he doesn't use over powered abilities some of these champs have. He says at one point:

> "... because I don't use champs that presses R to get kills."

I respond with,

> " Yeah, I don't use characters to get kills, **like** you."

He suddenly gets all defensive and we begin to argue how this word is used at all.

I believe if I were to say "unlike" instead of the word "like," he would be in right to be defensive, but he seems to disagree completely. Could you guys help me out on this one, thanks!

Comment: The comma just before *like* is critical. With the comma, you're asserting "I, like you, don't ..." (i.e. you're talking about something you and your friend have in common). Without it, you're associating "you" with "use characters to get kills" (i.e. talking about a difference between you and your friend). The problem is that commas get lost very easily in speech.

Comment: could you use a more generic example? I don't know what "use champs that presses R" means, so I can't tell if it means the same thing as "use characters" in your second sentence. Whether they mean the same thing or not will determine the meaning of "like" here.

Comment: @Lawrence the comma still allows the reading that "you" are someone who "uses characters to get kills".

Comment: "I don't use characters (to get kills,) like you." I think the sentence is fine, but in a more serious setting than a dispute with a friend you might want to consider using "unlike" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is ambiguous. It's is a valid reading of it as "I don't use characters to get kills, just as you don't use characters to get kills" and also a valid reading of it as "I don't use characters to get kills, the way you use characters to get kills".

English can be ambiguous sometimes. Sometimes in literary writing we deliberately want to be ambiguous, but most of the time it is counter to our wish to express something. As such, it's not an incorrect sentence, but it is a bad one.

The issue isn't the word *like* (indeed, *unlike* would have exactly the same ambiguity in reverse), but the fact that it's unclear whether the subject of the statement is yourself, or people who do "use characters to get kills".

Such ambiguity is best avoided by rephrasing:

> Yeah, like you, I don't use characters to get kills.

This is clearer in the "like you" having yourself as the subject.

Comment: You're absolutely right! During the conversation it was merely an after thought. I generally hold myself in a better standard of communicating, but after a few brews and staying up until 4 am, I was getting a little sloppy. Thanks again!